# Unreasonable censorship

Tags: support

I posted **two** basic comp sci questions to get **advice** on how to approach the problem. I wasn't look for a definitive solution.  I provided

1. An approach
2. Context
3. A problem
4. My attempt

I would appreciate it if my account could be unbanned. I am a published researcher, scientist, and textbook author. The community should be thanking me for my contributions since I've answered almost all of my own questions on stackoverflow and mathstackexchange. I take humility very seriously. I always recognize individuals for their contributions.

Comment: There is no censorship here; others downvoting your posts for valid (if not always entirely objective) reasons given in the comments is how these sites work.

Comment: FWIW: "I am a published researcher, scientist, and textbook author. The community should be thanking me for my contributions since I've answered almost all of my own questions on stackoverflow and mathstackexchange." -- that sounds like argument from authority to me, not like humility. Anyway, since you are a published researcher, I'm sure you're intimiately familiar with the value critical reviews have for the overall body of work in any field.

Comment: "I provided ... My attempt": this is a blatant lie. Also not sure what you mean by "I provided ... An approach".

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have received an automatic question ban, see this [help center article](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) for more information. This likely the consequence of your two questions being poorly received. Moderators cannot lift this ban. The recommended way to be allowed to post new questions is to improve your existing questions first.

As for why your questions have been poorly received, they are both specific instances of a type of question that is very common in algorithms courses (and therefore also frequently asked here), and can be solved by applying the techniques in mentioned in the questions suggested as duplicate.

If you want to improve your questions, I see you mentioned that the linked questions and answers to it were not helpful in answering your question. If you can explain why the information there did help you or have a concrete question about the linked material, you can use this to improve your question.

---

As an aside, while it is good to adhere to guidelines on the form of a question, they are not a guarantee for a good question. It also doesn't always convince others you have a good question, unfortunately. I do somewhat agree that the result here may be a bit harsh, but I still think improving your questions is the way to go.